# Using BIM 360 Docs API Is there any way to create project with existing project settings?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In the BIM360 docs account, our requirement is to create a project using **API** with existing project settings. i.e suppose we have already one project exists in which we have created **all custom attributes for issues in a project admin** and set some permission. We want to create all these attributes automatically while we create a new project, using this existed project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create new BIM 360 projects from a template project. If you check the sample setup tool at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360.project.setup.tool, you can see that it provides the feature to create a new project by copying the folder structure and folder permission from a template project, but you can't setup the custom attributes automatically at this moment because the API to create custom attribute is not available yet.

If you are interested in the new Custom Attributes API, please check it [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-custom-attributesbatch-update-POST/), be noted defining a custom attribute API is still working in progress.

Hope it answers your question.